# Switch/case without break inside DllMain

Tags: c, dll, winapi, switch-statement

I have a Dllmain that allocates Thread local storage when a thread attaches to this DLL. Code as below:

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    LPVOID lpvData; 
    BOOL fIgnore; 

    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        onProcessAttachDLL();
        // Allocate a TLS index.
        if ((dwTlsIndex = TlsAlloc()) == TLS_OUT_OF_INDEXES) 
            return FALSE; 
        // how can it jump to next case???
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        // Initialize the TLS index for this thread.
        lpvData = (LPVOID) LocalAlloc(LPTR, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE); 
        if (lpvData != NULL) 
            fIgnore = TlsSetValue(dwTlsIndex, lpvData);  
        break; 
    ...
```

}

I know that for the main thread, the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH is not entered, as per Microsoft Documentation. However, the above code worked. I am using VC2005. When I entered the debugger, I saw that after it entered DLL_THREAD_ATTACH case when ul_reason_for_call = 1! How can that happen? If I add `break' at the end of DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH block, the DLL failed to work.

How can this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are wondering why, after entering the `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` case, the execution continues on the `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` case, instead of after the end of the `switch`.

This behaviour is called "fall through", and it is standard C. Without an explicit `break` statement, the execution continues on the next `case`.

Of course, it is quite counterintuitive for programmers who see it the first time, so it is a constant source of misunderstanding and even bugs (you may not always know whether the `break` was left out intentionally, or by mistake). It is considered good practice, therefore, when using this construct, to mark it explicitly with a comment, like:

```
switch (ul_reason_for_call)
{
case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    onProcessAttachDLL();
    // Allocate a TLS index.
    if ((dwTlsIndex = TlsAlloc()) == TLS_OUT_OF_INDEXES) 
        return FALSE; 
    // fall through
case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    // Initialize the TLS index for this thread.
    lpvData = (LPVOID) LocalAlloc(LPTR, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE); 
    if (lpvData != NULL) 
        fIgnore = TlsSetValue(dwTlsIndex, lpvData);  
    break; 
...
```

Comment: Thanks. Although I have multi-year experience with C/C++, I never wrote such a construt. I always put break in each branch or multiple cases (sharing the same code block). It looks weird to me at the first.

Comment: @Sherwood Hu - Yes, it is weird at first sight :-) I realize that my wording might have felt degrading to you, so I reworded it. Now that you got a satisfying answer to your question, may I ask you to accept it, in line with SO conventions? Thanks.

Comment: An even better practice is to put the `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` code in a function of its own and call it from both `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`, while adding the "missing" `break`

Answer (score 1):

Do you understand how switch statements work?  if you do NOT put a break at the end of the case, then the code just continues into the next case:

```
switch (3)
{
case 3:
   cout << "3";
case 4:
   cout << "4";
}
```

prints both 3 and 4.